# how to filter a date only according to timezone?

Tags: angularjs, timezone, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-filters

I have a requirement to change timezone of the time coming from server back and forth, where the user edits the date.

```
<td>
    {{time | date:'shortTime':'+0500'}}                        
    <span uib-timepicker ng-model="time | date:'shortTime':'+0500'"></span>           
</td>
```

How do I make the user edit the time on a different timezone of that in actual time?

Comment: the timezone of the actual `time` variable shouldn't change. it should only display (editable) it to user in a preferred timezone

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly you just need to visually display the time differently to the user based upon how they selected it. The date filter is in the format date: dateformat : timezone so you can just bind timezone to a variable.

```
{{time | date:'shortTime': selectedTimeZone}}
```

then have something to select that variable with:

```
<select name="timezoneSelector" ng-model="selectedTimeZone">
  <option value="CST">Central Standard Time</option>
  <option value="GMT">Greenwich Mean Time</option>
</select>
```

I'm using timezone codes but you can also use offsets instead for example '+0430' will display 4 hours, 30 minutes east of the Greenwich meridian.

Comment: no issue while displaying, but what to do when i want the user to edit upon that time (which has been filtered according to the timezone). how do i apply filter on the model ? the actual variable in the model should be in UTC, where as the user should edit according to a particular timezone (may or may not be his local timezone)

Comment: if i just add a filter to the model, just like how i did above, the time gets filtered as `'shortTime'` which should not happen, as it should contain time in ISO, how do i not touch that part, but just change the timezone?

Comment: The ISO 8601 date returns an absolute moment in time. Only when is interpreted under the context of a timezone does it have any meaning. It really doesn't make sense to change the timezone of it.|

What you should be saving is the timezone the user selected. Then, simply apply the correct timezone to the date filter to display it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by modifying the model options

```
<span uib-timepicker ng-model="time" ng-model-options="{timezone: '+0500'}"></span>
```

Comment: i later figured out that [angular ui bootstrap](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/5594) doesn't support timezone for time picker
so had to use another [repo](https://github.com/Gillardo/bootstrap-ui-datetime-picker) which solved my purpose